# Можно ли заставить Chrome сохранять изменения в SCSS также, как он их сохраняет в CSS?

Tags: google-chrome, sass, scss, google-chrome-devtools

Вопрос для экспертов SASS/SCSS.

Если в Google Chrome в инструментах разработчика на вкладке Sources добавить в Filesystem папку со скриптами (рис 1), то все изменения CSS вносимые на вкладке Elements (рис 2), моментально сохраняются в CSS на жёстком диске (рис 3).

[image: вкладка Sources инструментов разработчика]

[image: изменения на вкладке Elements инструментов разработчика]

[image: откорректированный CSS-файл]

Также все изменения можно наблюдать на вкладке Changes (рис 4).

[image: изменения в инструментах разработчика]

Если получаю CSS из SCSS с сохранением sitemap, то браузер видит все стили как будто бы они берутся из SCSS (рис 2). Но, изменения всё также сохраняются только в файле CSS (рис 3), при этом код SCSS остаётся без изменений (рис 5).

[image: оригинальный файл SCSS остался без изменений]

Можно ли заставить Chrome работать с SCSS также как и с CSS? Или есть более эффективные способы корректировки стилей?

Answer (score 4):

Все гораздо проще! Распишу алгоритм, как это работает...

1. Сделали проект в котором руками создали `styles.css`, можно пустой;
2. Загрузили проект в `DevTools` в закладке `Sources`;
3. Открыли там `styles.css`;
4. Во внешнем редакторе изменили и сохранили содержимое `styles.css`;
5. `DevTools` должен автоматически увидеть изменения файла и перезагрузить его;

На этом этапе проверили, что `DevTools` "следит" за изменением. Если этого не происходит - ищем в сети хелп по настройке этого. Статей просто море, и нет смысла тут дублировать. По-умолчанию `DevTools` не генерирует `sourcemap файл`, а оно нам и не надо. Далее настраиваем sass-компилятор. Я советую [Koala](http://koala-app.com/). Хотя проект и закрыт уже, но все, что нужно (по крайней мере мне) - в нем есть.

6. Скачиваем, устанавливаем, открываем в нем проект, настраиваем автокомпиляцию и генерацию `sourcemap`;
7. Тестируем. Для этого внесем изменения в файл `styles.scss`, и нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> для сохранения файла;
8. Наблюдаем - должна произойти автокомпиляция, должен перезаписаться `styles.css`, он должен автозагрузиться в `DevTools`, должен создаться `sourcemap файл`, (и если открыта нужная страница в браузере - зразу должны произойти изменения в ней).

**Итог**

Бинго! Одно нажатие <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> - и все отработало автоматом.

**Замечания**

- Koala - имеет встроенные компиляторы, но можно и подключать внешние (допустим, более свежие, более свежего стандарта);
- Koala - много чего умеет, в том числе сжимать результирующие файлы (min-версии)
- Koala - капризничает, если в $HOME есть non-ASCII символы, но это решается, решение ниже.

```
!!! Не обязательно в C:/Users/Default/docker/.koala - куда пожелаете, главное, 
!!! чтобы в пути не было non-ASCII символов.

If you don't want to change you home folder name, try this:

Shut down the Koala. Move USER_HOME/.koala to C:/Users/Default/docker/.koala
use any path that is free of non ASCII chars.

in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\app\scripts\FileManager.js

replace:
exports.userDataDir = path.join(process.env[(process.platform === 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'], (process.platform === 'darwin') ? 'Library/Application Support/Koala/UserData' :'.koala');

with:
exports.userDataDir = 'C:/Users/Default/docker/.koala';

in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\app\scripts\pages\log.js
replace:
var errorLog = process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] + '/.koala/error.log';

with:
var errorLog = 'C:/Users/Default/docker/.koala/error.log';
```

Comment: так суть не в автосохранении и компиляции, суть в том, чтобы менять стили на вкладке Elements. То есть, например, я зашел на страничку сайта, вижу элемент, который мне нужно исправить, нажимаю правой кнопкой мыши, и выбираю **Inspect Element** и вижу в DevTools сразу все стили, которые влияют на этот элемент и сразу могу отредактировать их (например, подобрать нужный цвет или подобрать толщину бордюра), и изменения стразу сохранятся в CSS, а в SCSS не сохранятся.

Comment: Это противоречит идее `sourcemap`! Карта указывает именно на источник, который `*.scss`. Нужно значит менять подход. Навскидку ... перед манипуляциями с *.css удалять из него информацию об источнике.

Хотя стоп! По-моему в настройка DevTools где-то была настраиваемая опция "Использовать или нет sourcemap".

Comment: Вот гипотетический пример. Захожу на сайт, вижу что у меня уехал вниз блок. Я инспектирую элемент, вижу, что надо убавить margin (причем, заранее не знаю на сколько), ставлю курсор на нужное значение margin, перемещаю взгляд на блок, и стрелочками вверх-вниз изменяю размер margin пока блок не встанет на место. Каждое нажатие на клавишу имеет моментальный отклик. При этом, изменяя значение, я могу не смотреть на значение, а смотреть на сам элемент. В случае с редактированием значения в коде, это вряд ли получится, там надо стереть значение, вписать новое, сохраниться, подождать обновления

Comment: Кстати говоря, самая лучшая визуализация CSS сделана в Adobe Brackets. Но я около года полтора назад отказался от них в пользу Codium, и это как раз по причине того, что в нём реально всё работает из коробки. Установил, открыл проект, нажал на кнопочку ► и загрузился браузер с полностью настроенным Live Preview. Вообще ничего не надо настраивать, ни веб-сервер, ни вебсокеты для отслеживания изменений в CSS, ни авто-компиляцию SCSS. Изменения в SCSS через пол секунды отображаются на странице. Ребята молодцы, конечно вылизали этот Codium почти до идеала. Но в Brackets визуализация лучше конечно!

Comment: Дело в том, что реально реально непосредственно реализую идеи прямо в DevTools. В редакторе кода, конечно в целом, удобно редактировать и наблюдать структуру кода одновременно. Но, непосредственно, реализация мелких фичей в CSS/JS удобнее из DevTools. На половину самого DevTools открыта вкладка Elements и на другой половине - Console. В Elements набираешь весь код CSS, в консоли набираешь весь код JS. И моментально видишь результат. А уже потом всё это красиво оформляешь в редакторе кода. Правда, я никак не могу перейти на SCSS. Реально вот хочется, а браузер сцук  не даёт этого сделать!

Comment: Ну ёпрст! Да, правя `*.css` можно менять атрибуты и наблюдать изменения в отображении. Но сохранить на чужом сайте нельзя. И если редактируем `*.scss` да на чужом сайте ... сохранить тож не можем, скомпилировать тож не можем.

Comment: Так весь прикол в том, чтобы не править CSS, а настраивать, выбирать, переставлять. Видеть что делаешь, не развивая косоглазие, когда один глаз в код, второй на объекте.

Comment: Почему нельзя сохранить? Как раз таки можно выбрать локальную копию CSS на удаленный работающий сайт. посмотрите это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYyQv0CSZOE

Comment: Также есть расширение под все модные браузеры https://github.com/openstyles/stylus  и целый сайт с пользовательскими стилями: https://userstyles.org/ (сайт может находиться под DDOS-атакой).